# Cannot find module 'react' on Jenkins build container

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jenkins, build

Environment: jenkins:jenkins:lts.
I've installed NodeJS plugin.  I am trying to execute a build for a react project.  My project builds just fine outside of Jenkins, but when Jenkins tries to build it (here's my stage script):

```
stage ("Build") {
    nodejs(cacheLocationStrategy: workspace(), nodeJSInstallationName: 'Node 13.12') {
     sh label: '', script: 'cd weather-station-ui; npm run build'   // some block
    }
}
```

I've tried all I can but, my build fails with:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Warning: React version was set to "detect" in eslint-plugin-react settings, but the "react" package is not installed. Assuming latest React version for linting.
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Cannot find module: 'react'. Make sure this package is installed.
```

What is the best way to get Node/npm build support for Jenkins running in a container?

Thank you!

Comment: Does your package.json have react installed as a production dependency? - please include the `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have call **npm install** before **npm run build**

Comment: Doh!!! Why did I think npm run build would install by default?  Thank you!!!